# How to use render_to_string() to validate template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate the template being entered by the user

admin.py

```
class TemplatesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Templates

    def validate_temp(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        html = self.cleaned_data.get('html')
        html_form = render_to_string(html)
        try:
            HttpResponse(html_form)
        except TemplateSyntaxError as e:
            logger.error(f"email template of name={name}suffers syntax error ")
            raise e


class TemplateAdmin(TabbedDjangoJqueryTranslationAdmin):
    form = EmailTemplateForm
    list_display = ('name', 'code', 'subject_en', 'subject_ar')
    actions = None
    search_fields = ['name', 'code', 'text_en', 'text_ar',
                     'html_en', 'html_ar', 'subject_en', 'subject_ar']


admin.site.register(EmailTemplate, EmailTemplateAdmin)
```

is this trial correct or something is better

Comment: What is this you are rendering the template in ```forms.py``` instead of ```views.py```

Comment: its the admin.py
i need to validate

Comment: You should validate  in ```views.py``` like ```if fm.is_valid```

Comment: its an admin , no views.py here